# Is there a way to automatically convert a Greasemonkey script into a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, bookmarklet

For those who don't know what a bookmarklet is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no "automatic" way to achieve this but doing it manually shouldn't be too hard.

If the script *doesn't* depend on the **[GreaseMonkey API](http://wiki.greasespot.net/API_reference)** then it should be as simple as copy n' paste, perhaps with some **[minification](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)** to get it all on one line.

You'll probably want to wrap it all in the following code too:

```
javascript: (function(){ /* Your code here */ })();
```

Also, be aware of the limits (you can't have an infinitely long bookmarklet): **https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/limits.html**

Comment: You can bypass that limit by loading it with: javascript:with(document)(head.appendChild(createElement('script')).src='//example.com/my.js')._